# Is there a way to test a Dart program as unchecked (production) mode?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart

Some of my classes uses `assert()` to make development easier.

The problem is that those `asserts` are ignored in production mode, so I need a way to write tests for times when those assertions fail (when they throw assertionErrors).

```
main() {
  // test if the assertion is being throw correctly
  test('null emailStr assertion', () {
    expect(() => Email(emailStr: null), throwsAssertionError);
  });

  // here I want to test how it would behave in prod mode
  // when the asserts are ignored.
  // This way it'll just throw an assertion error
  test('null emailStr emailStr value', () {
    final Email email = Email(emailStr: null);
    expect(email.isValid, false);
  });
}
```

I wonder if there's something like this to run tests as if we were in production mode:

```
setUp(isCheckedMode = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in google that the only way to message someone in stack is to write a comment in his question.
However, my code of another class (MessageBubble) is:

```
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String messsage;
  final userID;
  final bool isMe;
  final Key key;
  MessageBubble(this.messsage,this.userID, this.isMe,this.key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: isMe? MainAxisAlignment.start: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isMe? Colors.grey[300]: nave,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
              topRight: Radius.circular(12),
              bottomLeft: !isMe ? Radius.circular(12) : Radius.circular(0),
              bottomRight: isMe ? Radius.circular(12) : Radius.circular(0),

            ),
          ),
          width: 140,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10,horizontal: 16),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  FutureBuilder(
                    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID).get(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if(snapshot.connectionState== ConnectionState.waiting){
                      return Text('جاري التحميل...');}
                      return Text(snapshot.data['username'], style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
                    }
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(messsage, style: TextStyle(color: isMe? white : Colors.black,),),
            ],
          ) ,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

my code in main:

```
 home:
      StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(), builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
        if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
          return ChatPage();
        }
        return FirstPage();
      }),
```